# Prevent Function from Changing Array

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I have a program containing multiple functions to edit an array. However, I notice that when I change the order of elements with a function, the effect is global on my original array. How can I fix this?

Function:

```
int descend(int *ary, int i, int l){
    
    int half = l / 2;

    for (i = 0; i < half; i++) {

      int temp = *(ary + i);
      *(ary + i) = *(ary + (l - 1 - i));
      *(ary + (l - 1 - i)) = temp;

        }
    
    printf("Your array descending is: ");
    
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) 
      printf("%d ", *(ary + i));

    printf("\n");
      
}
```

Driver code:

(under a switch)

```
 case 3:
   system("clear"); 
   descend(ptr, 0, n); // ptr is my main array pointer and n = length of array
   break;
```

The code prints the correct answer (1,2,3,4,5 -> 5,4,3,2,1), but my pointer is changed permanently as result instead of just being an output of the function. Should I instead be using `return`?

Comment: Make a copy of the original array if you don't want it to be changed.

Comment: MarcusQP,  "when I change the order of elements with a function, the effect is global on my original array" --> As code passes to `descend()` a pointer to the original array in `main()`, what array did you think was being changed with `*(ary + i) =  ...`?  Keep in mind with `descend(int *ary, int i, int l)`, `ary` is a _pointer_, not an _array_.

Comment: Style tip: use array subscripting — it is clearer.  Rather than: `*(ary + i) = *(ary + (l - 1 - i));` use `ary[i] = ary[l - 1 - i];`.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you, I've been trying this though and it's hurting my head. When I try to assign the original pointer's elements to a new pointer, the output is a bunch of nonsense. Gonna keep chipping away and I'll show my new code if I have issues. Thanks again